# Installing MySQL server 4.1 on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: mysql

how do I need to install mySQL server 4.1 on Ubuntu 11.04 server for a legacy app to run (it breaks on mySQL 5).

```
sudo apt-get mysql-server-4.1
```

doesn't work - "package is missing, obsoleted or available from another source".

Background:

I'm trying to migrate from a Windows Server to Ubuntu Server. I have a MS Visual Foxpro app connecting to mySQL server 4.1 on Windows.

Just trying to replicate that on Ubuntu for now.

So far, I've got it to the point where the app is already up and running from a remote machine (on mySQL 5.1). However, I have tested and verified that some functions don't work well and it is because of the difference in mySQL versions.

Invariably, someone would suggest that I tinker with the code. I can't do that yet as I didn't develop the app and am still negotiating for the source code.

In the meantime, my goal is just to get this thing to run in Ubuntu with as little hassle as possible and that requires mySQL server 4.1.

Thanks.

Comment: I have searched high and low in the archives of dev.mysql.com and the code for MySQL 4.1 is no longer available.

Comment: Please add to your question the functions that do not work, whether the function are PHP or MySQL.

Comment: You may have to resort to using another machine, installing a very old version of Ubuntu which may have the mysql-server-4.1 package (along with the client, dev, shared, and share-compat packages), transport them to the machine running Ubuntu 11.04, and try to install them.

Comment: Hmm, yes, that might work...however, I have no idea how to go about figuring out the dependencies.

Comment: Some still use MySQL 4.1. SkySQL has committed to supporting all versions of MySQL (even back to 3.23). So, your question get a +1 because it demonstrates that using MySQL 4.1 is still a viable option for many.

Answer (score 2):

If you can run 6.06 [in a VM](http://ns2.canonical.com/natty/qemu-kvm) on top of 11.04 server, it [looks like](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper/mysql-server-4.1) MySQL 4.1 can be installed on that

Comment: Of course, VM is way to go here for that other Ubuntu machine. Hopefully, if the MySQL 4.1 source code is there in the VM and it can be trred and dragged over, you may nailed this one. +1 for the VM approach.

Comment: I'm not recommending running 4.1 on 11.04 directly - just inside a VM *instead*

Comment: Actually, you are correct. (I just had a Homer Simpson DOH !!! moment, maybe too much coffee). Why hassle dragging source code when the machine needed is spun up in a VM with MySQL 4.1 readily available ? Good thinking !!!

Comment: 1) install debian 6 in a VM 2) spin up VM, log in as root, add debian sarge repo from archives 3) add debian signing key(s) as needed 4) apt-get install mysql-server-4.1 5)??? 6) profit!